# excel autofilter using xlAnd and xlOr

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I know I can technically only have two criteria with Autofilter.

I also know I can use an array to "add" more to an "And" or "Or" situation.

Example I found:

```
             Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter _
             Field:=1, _
             Criteria1:=Split("France#Belgium#Germany", "#"), _
             Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

However, I want to filter a column to all fields between two dates (one year) and include blanks.

There has to be a better way than making an array of every date for an entire year like I am thinking....?

This is one variation I have tried that doesn't work...

```
 Range("A1:AV1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=">=1/1/2018", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria3:="<=12/31/2018"
```

Help! Please!
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how an array of dates is too difficult.

```
dim d as long, dts as variant
redim dts(dateserial(2019, 1, 1)-dateserial(2018, 1, 1)+1)
dts(0) = vbnullstring
for d=dateserial(2018, 1, 1) to dateserial(2018, 12, 31)
    dts(d-dateserial(2018, 1, 1)+1) = Format(d, "m/d/yyyy") '<~~should match worksheet
next d
Range("A1:AV1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=dts, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: That does seem to work! Thanks! What I dont understand is how it keeps blanks without specifying to do so? I dont mind as it was the intent, but can you explain why? I upvoted this btw.

Comment: The blanks work because I put vbnullstring into the lbound element of the array. However, this also means that the dates have to be string dates matching the date format on the worksheet.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!                                                                  I found that the array also works well in the countif functions I have been needing.                                                                                      Z = Application.Sum(Application.CountIfs(Range("B:B"), "Z*", Range("S:S"), Eng, Range("E:E"), dts))         Thanks again!